# MYSQL rating algorithm

Tags: mysql, algorithm, rating

I have a MYSQL table which stores a rating for each event of a user, 1-10 in the events table called event_rating. What i'm trying to find is the highest accurate rating based on the number of votes and rating like this:

```
SELECT
 c.userid,
 c.user_name,
 COUNT(d.event_rating) AS votesCount,
 AVG(d.event_rating) AS votesAvg,
 SUM(d.event_rating) AS tsum,
 COUNT(d.event_rating)*AVG(d.event_rating)/COUNT(d.event_rating) as totalRating
FROM events d JOIN users c ON d.userid = c.userid WHERE (d.userid = '2') GROUP BY d.userid ORDER BY totalRating DESC
```

I added two dummy ratings for a user, one with a rating of 10 and another with 5.

The results are below:

```
 userid     user_name      votesCount       votesAvg    tsum      totalRating
   2    Rahul Khanna         2            7.5000        15        7.50000000
```

Is that accurate, and am i calculating it right?

**--- EDIT ---**

Posting Some more results

**USING** `COUNT(d.event_rating)*AVG(d.event_rating)/COUNT(d.event_rating) as totalRating`

```
userid  user_name   votesCount  votesAvg    tsum    totalRating
2      Rahul Khanna     2       7.5000       15      7.50000000
1      Rita Agnihotri   9       4.8889       44      4.88888889
3      Daniel Springs   4       3.5000       14      3.50000000
4      Roger Myers      6       3.5000       21      3.50000000
5      Chun Tanakat     3       3.0000       9       3.00000000
```

**USING** `COUNT(d.event_rating)*AVG(d.event_rating) as totalRating`

```
userid  user_name   votesCount  votesAvg    tsum    totalRating
1      Rita Agnihotri   9       4.8889       44      44.0000
4      Roger Myers      6       3.5000       21      21.0000
2      Rahul Khanna     2       7.5000       15      15.0000
3      Daniel Springs   4       3.5000       14      14.0000
5      Chun Tanakat     3       3.0000       9       9.0000
```

**--- MORE ---**

**Should i be using the below instead?**

```
COUNT(d.event_rating)*AVG(d.event_rating)/10 as totalRating
```

What i need is an accurate way to calculate the total rating, putting votesCount into consideration as well and that the rating has to be between 1-10.

**--- MORE DETAIL ---**

I have one table Users another Events, user is able to add new events and rate those events. The Events table has a eventID, userid, event_rating column. So each event can hold a rating for the event the user has created. What i want is to calculate all the events rating to get the max (total) rating for that user. I want the total rating i get to be between 1-10 and not exceed over 10 no matter how many events the user has created. Is that possible? if not any solutions or ideas?

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2):

What is this silly piece of query??

```
COUNT(d.event_rating)*AVG(d.event_rating)/COUNT(d.event_rating) as totalRating
```

This is nothing

`(a*b)/a` which is always b

you have to just fetch `AVG(d.event_rating)`

what do you want really ??

Comment: Updated my question with some more info and results.

Comment: Mathematically the problem still is the same: `COUNT(d.event_rating)*AVG(d.event_rating)/COUNT(d.event_rating) as totalRating` is equal to `AVG(d.event_rating) as totalRating` because `(a*b)/a` is `b`.

Comment: I'm not sure what my solution would be. Though to be more clear, as to what i am trying to accomplish i updated my question with more details.